# How to get two types of file from the intent?

Tags: java, android

This only allows to get image but i want users to be able to pick documents too.

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setType("image/*");
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"),PICK_IMAGE);
```

Comment: see `Intent#ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
intent.setType("application/x-excel|application/pdf|text/plain|text/csv|image/*");
startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
```

Comment: In ActivityResult what code i type becoz i need also this type of code

Comment: Surprisingly, this is not allowing images and text,but allowing everything else.

Comment: this is allow text in my device 
but **i don't want to take a .apk so how to i remove to select .apk**

Answer (score 0):

I have found very useful library on github that can help you to achieve what you want to do: `https://github.com/Applandeo/Material-File-Picker`

It allows you to define what types you want to select the options are

> APK, ARCHIVE, BOOK, DOCUMENT, IMAGE, MUSIC, SHEET, PDF, PRESENTATION,
>   TEXT and VIDEO.

You can use them all instead of `APK`.